# ngRoute dynamic url as first part of path

Tags: angularjs, django, url, routes, ngroute

I want to create dynamic URLs in my website. I'm using Angular in front-end with ngRoute. I want basicaly this URLs:

mysite.com/home

mysite.com/about

mysite.com/(station's name)/ - this is a page to each station I've created

but when I acces a station page like *whateverUrl*, I get the error:

**Cannot GET /whateverUrl/**

I tried create a route like */station/whateverURL* and worked! But I want the URL as short as possible.

My code below:

```
angular.module("app").config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    var apiVersion = "/api/v2/";

    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "/static/app/view/home.html",
        controller: "HomeController",
        resolve: {
            userData: function(commonService) {
                return commonService.get(apiVersion + "users/");
            }
        }
    }).when("/home/", {
        templateUrl: "/static/app/view/home.html",
        controller: "HomeController",
        resolve: {
            userData: function(commonService) {
                return commonService.get(apiVersion + "users/");
            }
        }
    }).when("/about/", {
         templateUrl: "/static/app/view/about.html"
    }).when("/:stationId/", {
        templateUrl: "/static/app/view/station.html",
        controller: "StationController",
        resolve: {
            stationData: function(commonService, $route) {
                return commonService.get(apiVersion + "stations/" + $route.current.params.stationId + "/");
        }
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is not related to your frontend but backend.

Angular will kick in after server sends the file and it is processed by the browser, but right now when you request a resource at `/whateverUrl/` your server doesn't know how to handle it and responds with 404 and a standard 404 message.

From the error that you posted:

```
Cannot GET /whateverUrl/
```

<s>I think I can assume that you have a Node/Express Server on the backend.</s>

<s>You just need to add a middleware that serves index.html to all your urls.</s>

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app
    .route('/*')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile("index.html")
    });
```

Based on the comments below, the backend server is django based and imo that needs some fixes. I'm not deleting the answer but obviously what I have posted doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I'm using django and backend is right. everything is ok when I run local

Comment: ok, the best way to check if there is an issue with backend is by checking the source open `view-source:mysite.com/whateverUrl/` if you see "Cannot GET /whateverUrl/" then it is your backend else if you see some html then its angular

Comment: when i open mysite.com/whateverUrl/ I get a blank page with Cannot GET /whateverUrl/. now I set everything in a route like mysite.com/w/whateverUrl and worked, but as I said I want the URL as short as possible.

Comment: I think its the backend controller/action that is causing the issue for you, I don't have any experience in django so I cannot help you with that. May be you can add a django tag to this question or start a new one.